# calling the system.schedule method in a generic context

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

I am trying to call the system.schedule method in a generic manner to help avoid scheduled job naming confusion like so:

```
 // Set my schedulable class to run.
private String setMyClassRunning(String jobName, String sch){
    SchedulableClass sc = new SchedulableClass();

    String scheduledId = scheduleJob(jobName, sch, sc);
    return scheduledId;
}

// Set a scheduled job to run. This function has been isolated to account for test scenarios.
// If this method is called in a testing context, then add "Test" to the job name to avoid conflicts 
// with already scheduled jobs.
private String scheduleJob(String jobName, String cronExpression, Object schedulableClass)
{
    if(Test.isRunningTest())
    {
        jobName = 'Test' + jobName;
    }
    return system.schedule(jobName, cronExpression, schedulableClass);  
}
```

However, when I try and save the code, I get the error "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: system.schedule(String, String, Object);

This is confusing as the [system method descriptions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_system.htm) clearly show that this method does exist.

I know that it is possible to schedule a job using the method on an individual class basis, but the point is I want to make this generic, so I don't have to re-write the testing name convention code every time. Can anyone help??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ive had a play with this in a dev instance and it seems changing your second functions arguments from

```
private String scheduleJob(String jobName, String cronExpression, Object schedulableClass)
```

to

```
private String scheduleJob(String jobName, String cronExpression, Schedulable schedulableClass)
```

fixes the error message.

**EDIT:** Ive now tested this in a dev instance and substituting 'Object' for 'Schedulable' works and the job does get created.

This blog also seems to be trying to achieve something similar to you: http://alexdberg.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/starting-apex-scheduled-jobs-without.html

Comment: Thanks Jon, that is exactly what I needed, works perfectly!